# SQL Server PatIndex what does the dot and hyphen mean? (PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%')

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I Googled and Googled then I Googled some more... However, I am unable to figure this one out.

What the heck does the dot and hyphen mean in the following SQL Server command (after the 9)...

PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%'

Here is the code at work...

```
declare @tv_raw table(recnum int identity(1, 1) primary key, rawdata nvarchar(max))
insert into @tv_raw(rawdata) values('Washington 40 New Orleans 32')
insert into @tv_raw(rawdata) values('St. Louis 23 Detroit 27')    

select SubString(rawdata, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', rawdata)+3,PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', rawdata))
from @tv_raw
```

Comment: the dot and hyphen are merely other search criteria in the list enclosed in []. So any digit 0-9, that is 0,1,2...,8,9 or a dot or hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patindex returns..

> Returns the starting position of the **first occurrence of a pattern** in a specified expression, or zeros if the pattern is not found, on all valid text and character data types

So it returns first position of any character found in pattern...see below modified examples

```
declare @tv_raw table(recnum int identity(1, 1) primary key, rawdata nvarchar(max))
insert into @tv_raw(rawdata) values('Wa0shington- 40 New Orleans 32')
insert into @tv_raw(rawdata) values('St.- Louis 23 Detroit 27')    

select PatIndex('%[0-9-]%', rawdata)
from @tv_raw
```

**Output:**

3
4